# Store files nams into Queue using Threads

Tags: multithreading

I have a requirement in which i have to work on all the files of directory, So for this i am thinking to break the requirement into two sets , where i am thinking in first part threads will put file into the Queue(Producer) and in the second part threads will read file from the queue and start processing them .

The problem i am facing is only only one thread is doing all the task of putting the file into the queue , rest all find the queue empty .

Reader class

```
package com.src.deloitte.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
public class MyReader
{
   int[] threads;
   private long counter = 0;
   final Queue exploreList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

   public MyReader(int arrayLen) {
         threads = new int[arrayLen];
    }

   public void count() {
     counter++;
    }

   public void done(int id, int counter) {
       threads[id] = counter;
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        MyReader me = new MyReader(5);
        me.scan("c:\\myDirectory");}

    void scan(String fileName)
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        exploreList.add(file);
       for(int i =0;i<threads.length;i++ )
       {
           FileExplorer explorer = new FileExplorer(i,this); 
           Thread t = new Thread(explorer);
           t.start();
       }
      }
    }
```

FileExplorer

```
public class FileExplorer implements Runnable {

    public int counter = 0;
    public MyReader owner;
    private int id;

    public FileExplorer(int id, MyReader owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +"Entering into the run method");
        while (!owner.exploreList.isEmpty()) {
                 try{
                File file = (File) owner.exploreList.remove();

                if (file.exists()) {

                    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                        doThemagic(file);
                    } else {

                        // add the files to the queue
                        File[] arr = file.listFiles();
                        if (arr != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                owner.exploreList.add(arr[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // silent kill :)
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             }


        owner.done(id, counter);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +"   " + "total of files : " + counter);
    }

    private void doThemagic(File file) {
        System.out.println(file.toString());
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scan function, you add 1 file to the queue, then your consumers all start, try to remove an item from the queue and quit if the queue is empty.

Only the thread that found that original file will keep running. Instead of waiting until the queue is empty, you might consider waiting until you're actually done (perhaps the queue is empty AND there's no chance that another thread will be adding to the queue).